# jQuery moving content from one div to sibling

Tags: jquery, slider, append

I have a grid of divs which flow off the screen and I have prev and next buttons which will control this content.

Basically, inside of each div I have some content and when the user clicks on prev, I want all of the content to move from the div it's in to the next div along, I have tried with some code but I'm not sure if I'm on the right tracks...

```
<div class="box"><img src="../images/two.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="box"><p>Lorum ipsum</p></div>
<div class="box"><img src="../images/three.jpg" alt="" /></div>

$('.prev').click(function(){                
   $('.box').each(function(){
      var $destination = $(this).prev('.box');
      $(this).html().appendTo($destination);
   });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what exactly your expected outcome is. However, the way I understood this is that you have content in each div and that if you click previous each div's content is moved into the div previous to it and if you click next each div's content is moved to the one next to it.

I used HTML like this (I added a few more divs for clarity):

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/19/3318010/Eraser.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="box"><p>Lorum ipsum</p></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/6/19/3318010/Script.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

And next/previous actions like this:

```
var $steps = $('.box');

$('.prev').click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < $steps.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            var $lastStep = $($steps[i - 1]);
            var $currentStep = $($steps[i]);

            $lastStep.html($currentStep.html());
            $currentStep.html('');
        };
    };
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    for (i = $steps.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (i + 1 < $steps.length) {
            var $currentStep = $($steps[i]);
            var $nextStep = $($steps[i + 1]);

            $nextStep.html($currentStep.html());
            $currentStep.html('');
        }
    };
});
```

What you see happening is now all content is moved together either to the previous or next set of divs.

If that is not what you are looking for, let me know. Also, you will need some indicator when to stop going previous or next or you will loose all of your content.

#### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJM3c/1/) - Moving all content to previous and next element

Comment: @green_arrow: You are very welcome. I wasn't quite sure what was required but I'm happy to see it helped.

Answer (score 1):

When using `appendTo()` , you **add** the div's content to the destination div. 
If you want the data in the destination div will be replaced by the data in the current div , apppendTo() is not what you need - but  `$(destination).text($(this).html())`